# Why would an OCX or DLL file need to be unregistered then re-registered?

Tags: dll, regsvr32

Why would an OCX or DLL file need to be unregistered then re-registered?

Why would this happen on machine on not others?

Comment: I think this should be on Superuser

Comment: Some changes to the DLL will normally require a reregistration. New COM interfaces for instance must be registered before use. It's possible that some of developers don't realize this if component registration is part of the DLL build process.

Comment: @Ranhiru: disagree. Registration of components can be a critical part of programming so it belongs here as does other questions about regsvr32

Answer (score 0):

It is a false statement. Component registration (OCX or DLL) by Regsvr32 utility depends on how it has been implemented by developer of that component. Developer can skip registration code and then running Regsvr32 will have no effect. For example developer can create an installation msi package for that purpose.

In theory developer should provide valid code that will do proper registration and unregistration of the component. If that is done correctly, than there is no need to unregister component in order to register it. Sometimes registration could fail if there is broken dependancies, check [Explanation of Regsvr32 usage and error messages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

if it changed location? if the registry were corrupted?